# Which approximation algorithm is used for sin() by compilers?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, simd, trigonometry

When I call the `sin()` function from `math.h`, on `MSVC` for example (or `GCC`), which kind of approximation is it used? Is it well know?

And which accuracy does it have?

If I use the `ippsSin` [IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-sin) `SIMD` function, for example, I can choose which accuracy (even if I don't know the approx algorithm). Using double, I feel good with the performance I get from `ippsSin_64fc_A26`, but I'm not able to quantify its error (which is specified as *guarantee 26 correctly rounded bits of significand, or 6.7E+7 ulps, or approximately 8 exact decimal digits;*), compared to the native/scalar `sin()`.

Is `sin()` more accurate? More than `ippsSin_64f_A53` also?

Just to give an idea if its worth to lose precision due to performances.

Comment: TLDR: It depends on the compiler you're using and which system you're running on. You have to look up each case individually.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: And which bit of the function domain you're using. For small inputs it may well end up being better if you roll your own Taylor expansion in case you hit a discontinuity if the method changes.

Comment: @Bathsheba For small inputs, the result is actually the input itself (for `sin`) or constant (for `cos`). Since a lot of floating point numbers are _really small_, you perfectly cover almost half the domain with a single instruction: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/

Comment: @Bathsheba what do you mean by "small input"? Its in radians, so 0 to 2pi is the range...

Comment: I’d say up to 1e-6 but would have to analyse carefully. Note that the function has a 2pi periodicity which is effectively half that with a sign reversal.

Comment: @Bathsheba I mean, the range I'm working on its 0 2pi. Which approx fit better in your opinion?